# OSMNx python program producing error "Graph Contains No edges"

Tags: python, precision, osmnx

In this following segment of code, I am able to produce a route and a corresponding map for the latitude and longitude when there is a difference of at least 1 between the coordinates.

However, when it comes to following, coordinates that only differentiate by decimal places (say you want to find a route across town) I get the error that there are no graph edges.

I assume this is because the program is interpreting the starting point to be the same as the ending point because of scale?

Thanks for any help!

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
import folium

ox.settings.log_console=True
ox.settings.use_cache=True

# define the start and end locations in latlng

start_lat = float(80.87399)
start_long = float(-117.92435)

end_lat = float(80.91732)
end_long = float(-117.93312)

# location where you want to find your route
place     = 'city, state, United States'

# find shortest route based on the mode of travel
mode      = 'walk'        # 'drive', 'bike', 'walk'

# find shortest path based on distance or time
optimizer = 'length'        # 'length','time'

# create graph from OSM within the boundaries of some
# geocodable place(s)
graph = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type = mode, simplify=True, retain_all=False )
orig_node = ox.nearest_nodes(graph, start_lat,start_long)
dest_node = ox.nearest_nodes(graph, end_lat,end_long)
shortest_route = nx.shortest_path(graph,
                                  orig_node,
                                  dest_node,
                                  weight=optimizer)
route_map = ox.plot_route_folium(graph, shortest_route)
route_map.save('route5.html')

'''
```

Comment: Hard to guess without a reproducible example. But it looks like you swapped the X and Y arguments when you called the nearest_nodes function.

Comment: Yep that fixed it, switched around my values and it indeed spat out my map! Thanks